How to replace aar library with project source in Android?
I have a project in Android that uses an AAR library like below:
implementation files('libs/release.aar')

How can I replace it with the actual project source code (from a different project and directory) instead?
I tried replacing the line with this:
releaseFromSourceImplementation project(':projectSource')

And also in settings.gradle I added this:
include ':projectSource'

project(':projectSource').projectDir = file('../../projectSource')

But it doesn't work.
